# Express 4 - Destroy all sessions from an admin request

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I want the admin of an application to be able to destroy all regular user's sessions.

In express 4, we can destroy a session using

```
req.session.destroy();
```

but this function destroy the session attached to the request. Is there a way to destroy all sessions except the current request session which is the admin's session? How can I access all sessions from a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the session store do you use. You need to delete sessions from it.

If you use MongoDB, you can easily remove the specified sessions:

```
db.sessions.remove({admin:false})
```

With redis, the easiest way flush he whole database, but you will delete your current session too.

```
flush db
```

You can iterate over the keys and delete it one by one, but I don't recommend it.  The redis `keys(*)` lock the database, and with a million user, it can be a big problem.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but I am looking in a way to use store.destroy() as explained here: https://github.com/expressjs/session#storedestroysid-callback

Comment: You can use that only, if you know the `sid`. But if you check the source code, basically what I suggest is the same: Simply delete the record from the database. https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js#L197

Comment: Your solution is good, I just wonder how to use the session API to achieve it, ie: how to access the store object from a request

Comment: There should be a function for this: [store.all](https://github.com/expressjs/session#storeallcallback) but this is not implemented in [connect-redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis/blob/master/lib/connect-redis.js) or [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo/blob/master/src/index.js)

Comment: ok! It depends of the session-store... I understand. I am using connect-sqlite3 and it's not implemented neither. Your solution is the best then. Thank you!